# Using get and set methods with arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, get, set

Part of a java assignment I have requires me to use a set method to input details into an array. So far I have the following method to set the details

```
public void setCanopy(String uniqueRef, String modelName, int width, int height, int depth, int crewToBuild, double timeToBuild, double trailerLength, String available)
{
    this.uniqueRef = uniqueRef;
    this.modelName = modelName;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.depth = depth;
    this.timeToBuild = timeToBuild;
    this.available = available;
    this.crewToBuild = crewToBuild;
    this.trailerLength = trailerLength;     
}
```

This method works fine as long as it's only used to input details to a constructor, but when I try to use it with an array I get a NullPointerException.

I also have to display these details later on using get methods. I'm using the following method to display these but again, it only works if I'm using constructors.

```
public static void displayCanopyDetails(Canopy c)
{
    System.out.println("Canopy reference number: " + c.getUniqueRef() + "\nCanopy model name: " + c.getModelName() + 
    "\nCanopy Dimensions (cm) - Width: " + c.getWidth() + " Height: " + c.getHeight() + " Depth: " + c.getDepth() +
    "\nCrew to build: " + c.getCrewToBuild() + "\nTime to build canopy (minutes): " + c.getTimeToBuild() + 
    "\nTrailer Length: " + c.getTrailerLength() + "\nAvailability: " + c.getAvailable());
}
```

Any help getting these working with arrays would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

In my main method I have

```
tentDetails(c[0]);
```

which calls the method

```
public static void tentDetails(Canopy c1,)
{
    c1.setCanopy("CAN123", "Model1", 500, 200, 500, 5, 15, 10, "Available");
}
```

The NullPointerException error happens when it tries to run this method.

Comment: Where's the code that doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by:"but when I try to use it with an array I get a NullPointerException" ?

Comment: You need to use constructor because otherwise there is no object created. If you use an array for example 
     Canopy[]  canopy=new Canopy[5];
And then Canopy[1].object=5 you get NullPointer because the array gives you object storage but initializing array doesn't create the objects inside. they are nulls. If you check Canopy[1] it is null..

Comment: I've updated my post to show the method which tries to input details to the array. This is where the NullPointerException occurs.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the array it creates an empty "bag" for objects but it doesn't create the objects themselves. When you use a method on an object in this array you get NullPointerException because the object is null. You cannot execute methods on an object before creating it first. For example:

```
Canopy[] canopy=new Canopy[5];  //Creates a 'storage' for 5 Canopy objects
System.out.println(Canopy[0]); //Prints null and throws NPE if you execute method

Canopy[0]=new Canopy();  //Create new Canopy object and insert it in the array

System.out.println(Canopy[0]); //Not null anymore - you can execute methods
Canopy[0].setCanopy("CAN123", "Model1", 500, 200, 500, 5, 15, 10, "Available"); // works fine
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java the rule is that when you create an array its elements receive the default value. An Object's default value is null, therefore initially each element in your array is null. You have to explicitly instantiate the Canopy objects like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    c[i] = new Canopy();
}
```

After this, you can safely call the tentDetails() method on each element of your array.